# I want to display the price value for selected items using switch statement

Tags: javascript

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Switch Statement and Labeled Break</title>
    <script>
    addEvent(window, ‘load’, initialize);
    function initialize()
    {
    // add an event to the drop down list
    addEvent(document.getElementById(’chips’), ‘change’, getPrice);
    }
    function product(name, price)
    {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    }
    var ICs = new Array();
    ICs[0] = new product("Septium 900MHz", "$149");
    ICs[1] = new product("Septium Pro 1.0GHz", "$249");
    ICs[2] = new product("Octium BFD 750MHz", "$329");
    var snacks = new Array();
    snacks[0] = new product("Rays Potato Chips", "$1.79");
    snacks[1] = new product("Cheezey-ettes", "$1.59");
    snacks[2] = new product("Tortilla Flats", "$2.29");
    // lookup in the ‘table’ the cost associated with the product
    function getPrice()
    {
    var chipName = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    var chipType = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    var outField = document.getElementById(’cost’);
    master:
    switch(chipType)
    {
    case "ICs":
      for (var i = 0; i < ICs.length; i++)
      {
      if (ICs[i].name == chipName)
      {
      outField.value = ICs[i].price;
      break master;
      }
    }
      break;
    case "snacks":
      for (var i = 0; i < snacks.length; i++)
      {
      if (snacks[i].name == chipName)
      {
      outField.value = snacks[i].price;
      break master;
      }
    }
    
     }
      break;
    default:
    outField.value = "Not Found";
    }
     }
    
    
    
    
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Switch Statement and Labeled Break</h1>
    <p>Select a chip for lookup in the chip price table:</p>
    <form id="theForm">
    <p>
    <label for="chips">Chip:</label>
    <select id="chips">
       <option></option>
       <option value="ICs">Septium 900MHz</option>
       <option value="ICs">Septium Pro 1.0GHz</option>
       <option value="ICs">Octium BFD 750MHz</option>
       <option value="snacks">Rays Potato Chips</option>
       <option value="snacks">Cheezey-ettes</option>
       <option value="snacks">Tortilla Flats</option>
       <option>Poker Chipset</option>
    </select>
    <label for="cost">&nbsp; Price:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cost" size="10">
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

// In the above code snippets  I am trying to show the price for selected chip ,but no price is being shown in the input field.I have attached the output screen shot.I have built two arrays with a custom object ,simulating two database tables.
I am also defining one function getPrice for associating the price related to the product.
Thanks in advance 
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyjFh.png)

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
       <title>Switch Statement and Labeled Break</title>
       <script>
            window.onload = initialize;

            function initialize()
            {
                document.getElementById('chips').addEventListener('change', getPrice);
            }
            function product(name, price)
            {
               this.name = name;
               this.price = price;
            };

            var ICs = new Array();
            ICs[0] = new product("Septium 900MHz", "$149");
            ICs[1] = new product("Septium Pro 1.0GHz", "$249");
            ICs[2] = new product("Octium BFD 750MHz", "$329");

            var snacks = new Array();
            snacks[0] = new product("Rays Potato Chips", "$1.79");
            snacks[1] = new product("Cheezey-ettes", "$1.59");
            snacks[2] = new product("Tortilla Flats", "$2.29");

            function getPrice()
            {
                var selectelem = document.getElementById("chips"), outField = document.getElementById('cost'), outvalue="";;
                var chipName = selectelem.options[selectelem.selectedIndex].text;
                var chipType = selectelem.value;
                if(!chipType)
                {
                    outField.value = ""; return;
                }
                switch(chipType)
                {
                    case "ICs":
                        var arr = ICs.filter(function(item){
                            return item.name == chipName;
                        });
                        outvalue = arr[0].price;
                        break;
                    case "snacks":
                        var arr = snacks.filter(function(item){
                            return item.name == chipName;
                        });
                        outvalue = arr[0].price;
                        break;
                    default: outvalue = "Not Found"; break;
                }
                outField.value = outvalue;
            }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Switch Statement and Labeled Break</h1>
       <p>Select a chip for lookup in the chip price table:</p>
       <form id="theForm">
          <p>
             <label for="chips">Chip:</label>
             <select id="chips">
                <option></option>
                <option value="ICs">Septium 900MHz</option>
                <option value="ICs">Septium Pro 1.0GHz</option>
                <option value="ICs">Octium BFD 750MHz</option>
                <option value="snacks">Rays Potato Chips</option>
                <option value="snacks">Cheezey-ettes</option>
                <option value="snacks">Tortilla Flats</option>
                <option value="signals">TCP</option>
                <option value="computer">Poker Chipset</option>
             </select>
             <label for="cost">&nbsp; Price:</label>
             <input type="text" id="cost" size="10">
</p> </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks @vignesh ,I am not getting the logic of outvalue = arr[0].price i.e how arr[0] is suitable here

Comment: Filter returns an array of matching values. Since you have unique values, the filtered array contains only one object. So using arr[0].

Comment: Thanks a lot..@vignesh

Answer (score 0):

The switch is wrong. Should be something like this:

```
        switch (chipType) {
            case "ICs":
                for (var i = 0; i < ICs.length; i++) {
                    if (ICs[i].name == chipName) {
                        outField.value = ICs[i].price;
                        break master;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "snacks":
                for (var i = 0; i < snacks.length; i++) {
                    if (snacks[i].name == chipName) {
                        outField.value = snacks[i].price;
                        break master;
                    }
                }
            break;
            default:
                outField.value = "Not Found";
                break;
        }
```

Instead of AddEvent, you can use addEventListener. For example:

```
        var chips = document.getElementById('chips');
        chips.addEventListener('change', getPrice);
```